# Algorithm to calculate the price volatility of a commodity

Tags: algorithm, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to design an algorithm to calculate how volatile the price fluctuations of a commodity are.

The way I would like this to work is that if the price of a commodity constantly goes up and down, it should have a higher score than if the price of the commodity gradually increases and then falls in price rapidly.

Here is an example of what I mean:

Commodity A: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1

Commodity B: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 2

Commodity C: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2-> 1

Commodity A has a 'wave' like pattern in that its price goes up and falls down on a regular basis.

Commodity B has a 'cliff' like pattern in that the price goes up gradually and then falls steeply.

Commodity C has a 'hill' like pattern in that the price rises gradually and then falls gradually.

A should receive the highest ranking, followed by C, followed by B. The more of a wave pattern the price of the commodity follows, the higher a ranking it should have.

Does have any suggestions for an algorithm that could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I came up with an approach let me post it here .... looks like it should do the work

Comment: All you need to do is measure the distribution of price differentials, or the log of price ratios; the standard deviation of these distributions are canonical measures of volatility. A separate measure would then be the timepoint-to-timepoint correlation in these differentials. High correlation implies greater trendiness and less volatility.

Comment: @jwimberley thanks for the suggestion. Would you be able to provide an example to better illustrate what you mean? I am trying to make sense of it but don't fully understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Approach looks something like this.

For my algorithm, I am considering the above example.

```
A: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1

B: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 2

C: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2-> 1
```

Now I will squash these list, by squash i mean taking the start value and end value of an increasing or decreasing sequence.

So, after squashing the list will look something like this.

```
A: 1 -> 3 -> 1 -> 4 -> 1
B: 1 -> 8 -> 2
C: 1 -> 5 -> 1
```

Now once this it done, I take the difference between i and i+1 element and then take the average and based on the average, I give them the rank.

So the difference between i and i+1 element will look something like this

```
      2    2     3      3
A: 1 --> 3 --> 1 --> 4 --> 1  

      7     6
B: 1 --> 8 --> 2

     4      4
C: 1 --> 5 --> 1
```

Now let's sum this difference and take the average.

```
A: (2+2+3+3)/4 = 2.5
B: (7+6)/2 = 6.5
C: (4+4)/2 = 4
```

Now we can assign ranks based on this average value where

```
A < C < B
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow @zenwraight this does indeed look very promising. I will give it a try and see how it performs. Many thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi @badcoder anytime, I liked the question a lot, give it a try :)

Comment: quick question: what would you suggest to do when the price doesn't change much (or at all)? E.g:1 -> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1 is pretty much a flat line and the least volatile out of all of them, so should have the worst rank. If I get the average of all the numbers in this case, I just get the original number. So e.g. 6 -> 6 -> 6 -> 6 -> 6 would be 6, whereas 1 -> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1 would be 1. This does not make sense since they are both flat lines with no movement, but rank differently. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For a case like this we can make a case, like this will be a corner case .... what do you say ? like we can keep a change counter and if the change counter is 0 then we assign it rank equal to n where n is number commodities involved ...

Comment: I know coming up with a generalized solution would be better, let me give it more thinking, I will go home and think about this more, hopefully I will be able to come up with a good generalized solution

Comment: With all due respect, either of const-lines, be it 1-1-1-..-1, or 6-6-6-..-6 **yield 0** ( not 1 or 6 ) from the very first differentiating-step **(A)** ( sum-of-zero-deltas is zero, always, even if divided by N-elements in time-series ).